# Which characters to escape in string consisting of HTML tags and attributes?

Tags: javascript

I have a document.write statement that I'm using to write some HTML. My question is, do I need to escape anything more than the / and "" ?

```
document.write('<div style=\"display:none;\"><\/div>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to escape the double quotes in this string - that's only necessary if you enclose your string *with* double quotes.

You shouldn't need to escape your `/`es either; they don't break the string and `document.write()` (afaik) allows plain HTML to be inserted.

Comment: FYI - HTML Tidy recommends to escape the /. It wasn't an error, but rather a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape:

- `'` because that character is used to delimit the string
- `\` because that is an escape character
- new lines (as `\n`) since you cannot have a literal new line in the middle of a string in JavaScript

You do not need to escape `"` since they are not used to delimit this string.

You do not need to escape `/` except when it immediately follows a `<`, and even then only when you have HTML inside a `<script>` element instead of in an external file (but it does no harm to do so the rest of the time).

Comment: Could you explain about escaping the ' in my code above? I'm confused.

Comment: Since you have `'some html'` then if you had `'some html with a ' in it'` then you would have a syntax error, hence you would need `'some html with a \' in it'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin. I thought you were referring to the outer string delimiters. I'm clear now.

Comment: Minor nitpick: not all occurrences of `</` need to be escaped (although that’s probably the easiest solution). [Only the full `</script` string followed by any space character, `>`, or `/` will end the respective opening tag.](http://mths.be/etago)

Comment: @Mathias Bynens — As that document says, it is required for standards compliant HTML 4.

Comment: @Quentin Sure. I’d say it doesn’t really matter though, as no browser really implemented HTML4’s overly strict ETAGO-in-script rules. (Also, I don’t know why anyone would use HTML4 over HTML5.)

Comment: @MathiasBynens — It matters as it creates noise when performing validation. HTML 4 may be preferred over HTML 5 as it has a specification that is not a draft.